# Open IE URL in windows 8 app mode NOT desktop mode

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript

I need to open and IE page from a VBScript that is run by a batch file in Windows 8 app mode, not desktop mode.  This is so that users can use the swipe feature between IE and the desktop on a tablet.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

This is a bit of code that will open IE and go to the URL:

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

urlLine = "https://www.google.com/"

IE.Navigate urlLine
IE.Visible = True
```

I have tried setting the default browser and settings to Metro mode, but it still opens in desktop mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [IE Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)), then you can use:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWSH.Run "iexplore.exe -k http://www.myweb.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Kiosk mode is not the same as metro mode for windows 8.1.  Kiosk only opens IE as full screen within the desktop whereas metro mode will launch IE in the app mode, separate from the desktop.  Please let me know if you know of a way to activate metro mode from VBScript.